# Run/Execute a query in gsp/view in Grails

Tags: grails

Image controller has a function

```
def scaled = {
    log.debug("SCALED IMAGE " + params)
    response.setContentType('image/jpeg')
    response.setHeader('Cache-control', 'no-cache')
    def userId = session.selectedUser.id
    if(params.userId){
      userId = params.userId
    }
    if(params?.id != null && !(params?.id.empty)){
      params.maxWidth?: 20.00
      params.maxHeight?: 20.00
      response.outputStream << imageProxyService.loadImage(params.id, securityService.passwordEncoder(userId.toString()),params.maxWidth, params.maxHeight)
    }
  }
```

and profile photo's filename are stored in user table.
User has many status and i want to load user's profile photos depending on the statuses displayed. My status gsp looks like this:

```
<g:each in="${statusList}" status="i" var="status" status="i">
          <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <tr><td><img id="profile_photo" src="${createLink(controller:'image', action:'profilePhoto', id:status.photo)}" alt="" title="" />
              </td></tr>
          </tr>
        </g:each>
```

query I used in status controller:

```
def alllist = {
        log.debug("BEGIN IWI PROFILE")
        def statusList = []


            def sql = new Sql(dataSource);

            def statusQuery = """SELECT c.id, c.status_message, c.status_type as profile, se.id, se.photo FROM user_account se, status c
                    WHERE
                    c.user_account_id = se.id
                    GROUP BY se.id, c.id, c.status_message, c.status_type, se.photo"""


            def result = sql.rows(statusQuery);

            def userQuery = """not sure """
            if (result){
                log.debug("GOT SOME RESULTS IN PERSONAL user" + result)
                result.each() { status ->
                    def userResult = sql.firstRow(userQuery, [status.id])
                    if (userResult){
                        status['userId'] = userResult.id
                    } else {
                        status['userId'] = ""
                    }
                    statusList += status
                }
            }


        render(template: "alllist", model: [statusList: statusList])
```

Please Note: This way I am getting all the photos all right but photos display only for the session user.

```
<img id="profile_photo" src="/myApp/image/profilePhoto/9edd692580d148c791c6c2aa3510605a95ba6de6.jpg" alt="" title=""/>
```

Comment: Can you post your domain objects?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a TagLib. How you actually render the photo depends on what is stored in the UserAccount.photo field. I'll assume it's an absolute URL to an image.

```
class UserTagLib {

    def photo = {attrs ->
        UserAccount u = attrs.user
        out << "<img src=${u.photo}/>"
    }

}
```

You would use it in your GSP like:

```
<user:photo user="${status.userAccount}"/>
```

..assuming you are looping over a list of Status objects in a variable called status

Comment: very helpful...
what if i was only storing the filename.jpg into photo then how can i go about it?
also is there any way of using the image tag dynamically.
yours is: <img src=${u.photo}/>
can i use <img src=/images/${u.photo} />
will it accept it?

Comment: Here's an example I found: http://gamerzfever.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/render-image-file-located-outside-application-context-in-gsp-grails/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
<img src="http://applicationUrl/images/${u.photo}" />
```

or

```
<img src="${createLink(dir:'images',file: u.photo}" />
```

they can be used but as create link is deprecated now, I recommend using:

Resource for the same

```
<img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'file.jpg')}"/>
```

More information can be found at:

http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/resource.html

about the resources

Comment: Thanks this is syntex i was looking for...
more learning... how can I set the image var in a local variable and use it that way in an each tag?

Comment: http://devdevdev.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/displaying-images-from-database-records-in-grails-pages/

Check this one I think it should help you to render image on the GSP from the data base

Comment: thats helpful... I am down to run 2 queries in one action so i can get status information with 1st query and user info and photo with 2nd query depending on the status... do i need to use 2nd query inside each loop... please help

Comment: You can create a map and store the information from the queries, and at the end render the map, or if you can post some code in your action then I may able to help a bit more.
:)